# Is there file locking in Rust?

Tags: synchronization, locking, rust

I cannot find anything resembling file locking like some programs use in Linux to prevent multiple instances from running. In Python, I'd use [pylockfile](https://github.com/openstack/pylockfile).

Am I overlooking similar functionality in Rust, or should I just implement it from scratch?

<sub>I'm not lazy, just trying to reinvent as few wheels as possible.</sub>

Comment: There's come [code to start from](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/librustdoc/flock.rs) in rustdoc. It does say "This is not meant to be in the standard library".

Comment: I think you may have to implement it from scratch. The IO/OS module is still very much in flux, and it is uncertain whether this functionality would or would not be a good fit for it... that being said, Rust has embraced packages distribution though Cargo from the start precisely for this reason, so create a small package dedicated to this functionality and share it with the world via crates.io

Comment: It's been a while since I had to think hard about file locking implementations, but that Python library seems like it is not thorough enough. It seems to mostly work by creating files / directories and seeing if they exist, not relying on the OS facilities. If you do reimplement file locking, I'd suggest checking out other resources to see how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your replies! I sure meant creating an external library, not adding things to std.

Comment: BTW, if you want to create a daemon, then you would probably want to consider using your OS process management system, like `systemd` in Linux or `launchd` in OS X. That way you won't need to think about locks entirely.

Comment: see: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/flock.2.html for the official linux system call for file locking. It is *not* cross-platform

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For contemporary Rust (1.8+) you should use the [`fs2` crate](https://docs.rs/fs2/0.4.2/fs2/trait.FileExt.html). It is a cross-platform library that provides some file system functions not found in the standard library, including file locking.

`fs2`'s file locking functions internally use [`flock(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/flock) on UNIX and [`LockFileEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365203.aspx) on Windows.

Example:

```
//! This program tries to lock a file, sleeps for N seconds, and then unlocks the file.

// cargo-deps: fs2
extern crate fs2;

use fs2::FileExt;
use std::io::Result;
use std::env::args;
use std::fs::File;
use std::time::Duration;
use std::thread::sleep;

fn main() {
    run().unwrap();
}

fn run() -> Result<()> {
    let sleep_seconds = args().nth(1).and_then(|arg| arg.parse().ok()).unwrap_or(0);
    let sleep_duration = Duration::from_secs(sleep_seconds);

    let file = File::open("file.lock")?;

    println!("{}: Preparing to lock file.", sleep_seconds);
    file.lock_exclusive()?; // block until this process can lock the file
    println!("{}: Obtained lock.", sleep_seconds);

    sleep(sleep_duration);

    println!("{}: Sleep completed", sleep_seconds);
    file.unlock()?;
    println!("{}: Released lock, returning", sleep_seconds);

    Ok(())
}
```

We can see that the two processes are sequenced waiting on the file lock.

```
$ ./a 4 & ./a 1
[1] 14894
4: Preparing to lock file.
4: Obtained lock.
1: Preparing to lock file.
4: Sleep completed
4: Released lock, returning
1: Obtained lock.
1: Sleep completed
1: Released lock, returning
[1]+  Done                    ./a 4
```

Comment: Its not maintained for a very long time. There are a few open issues about its not working properly on OSX. There seems to be a more maintained fork of this crate here https://github.com/al8n/fs4-rs .

Answer (score 6):

In Linux you can use [nix crate](https://crates.io/crates/nix) which [wraps](https://github.com/carllerche/nix-rust/blob/master/src/fcntl.rs) unix file lock.

Here is an example:

```
extern crate nix;

use std::fs::File;
use std::os::unix::io::AsRawFd;
use nix::fcntl::{flock, FlockArg};

fn main() {
    let file = File::open("Cargo.toml").unwrap();
    let fd = file.as_raw_fd();
    flock(fd, FlockArg::LockExclusive).unwrap();

    for rem in (1..20).rev() {
        println!("Remain: {} sec.", rem);
        std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1));
    }

    drop(file);
    println!("File unlocked!");
}
```

If you try to run two instances, the second will start to countdown only after first instance unlocked file. But another programs can ignore this lock:

> **flock(2)**: function places advisory locks only; given suitable permissions on a file, a
>   process is free to ignore the use of flock() and perform I/O on the file.

Answer (score 2):

There's the [`advisory-lock`](https://github.com/topecongiro/advisory-lock-rs) crate as a cross-platform solution too.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/clucompany/cluFlock

```rust
use cluFlock::ToFlock;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io;

fn main() -> Result<(), io::Error> {
    let file_lock = File::create("/tmp/1")?.wait_exclusive_lock()?;

    println!("{:?}", file_lock);
    drop(file_lock); //<-- unlock file

    Ok( () )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As `fs2` seems to be no longer maintained, another option is [`file-lock`](https://crates.io/crates/file-lock).

Comment: https://github.com/al8n/fs4-rs is a maintained fork.