# Atomic file create & write

Tags: rust, atomic

I want to create a new file and write some data into it (there will be no other writes after that). Modern Rust provides a convenient function [`fs::write()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.write.html), but I want to make sure no other process would ever be able to read that file with *partially* written data.

Is there a function in Rust that does that directly or should I have to do that "manually" like this:

```
let mut f = File::create(FILE_TEMP)?;
f.write_all(some_data)?;
fs::rename(FILE_TEMP, FILE_FINAL)?;
```

I generally target Linux, but a cross-platform solution would be best.

Comment: Two existing answers mention locking the file. This might be fine, but this would still allow reading partial data if the writing application crashes, is killed, or gets interrupted in any way (eg. power failure). In that case the intermediary file + rename is more robust.

Comment: Keep in mind that most if not all solutions are based on *advisory* file locking.  A process that doesn't want to see partial data has to explicitly take the lock before reading.  If it just goes ahead and reads anyway, it'll get whatever is there.

Comment: Your existing solution is pretty much the optimal approach. Note that you can still use `std::fs::write()`, just give it `FILE_TEMP` as the file name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me there is no better solution than the one posted in the question, but in a slightly shortened form (thanks to user4815162342 for the note):

```
fs::write(FILE_TEMP, some_data)?;
fs::rename(FILE_TEMP, FILE_FINAL)?;
```

The lock-based solutions don't really seem to solve anything for this particular case. Also, they require a lot more code and are generally more error-prone.

The only potential side effect of my approach that I can think of is that if a problem during write occurs, we might end up having some dangling temp files. Some might see that as a problem, some might see it as a good thing, which might help in troubleshooting, etc. Also, if we prefer the OS to automatically clean up those dangling temp files for us, we could simply make `FILE_TEMP` point to the system's temp folder (given it is on the same filesystem /see the comments below/, otherwise the `fs::rename()` function will fail). That's why I personally see that more as a good thing.

Comment: At least on Linux, creating the temp file in the system temp directory (usually `/tmp`) is not likely to work. `rename` only works if the source and destination files are on the same filesystem; /tmp is usually an in-memory filesystem. I think the best practice is to create the temp file in the same directory as the destination.

Comment: @jmou You are correct about the filesystems - the temp folder must be on the same file system (I added this info in my answer). I checked 3 different Ubuntu 18/20 VMs - in all of them `/tmp` seemed to be on the "main" filesystem `/dev/vda1` (I used `df /tmp` to check that).

Comment: Good clarification! Fedora and Arch default to tmpfs for /tmp.

Answer (score 0):

The `fs2` crate has a function that can lock a file for exclusive access:

https://docs.rs/fs2/0.4.3/fs2/trait.FileExt.html

> File locks are implemented with [flock(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/flock.2.html) on Unix and [LockFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365202(v=vs.85).aspx) on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can lock the file using the [fs2 crate](https://docs.rs/fs2/0.4.2/fs2/). Here is an example that locks a file, taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45040455/9710458).

```rust
//! This program tries to lock a file, sleeps for N seconds, and then unlocks the file.

// cargo-deps: fs2
extern crate fs2;

use fs2::FileExt;
use std::io::Result;
use std::env::args;
use std::fs::File;
use std::time::Duration;
use std::thread::sleep;

fn main() {
    run().unwrap();
}

fn run() -> Result<()> {
    let sleep_seconds = args().nth(1).and_then(|arg| arg.parse().ok()).unwrap_or(0);
    let sleep_duration = Duration::from_secs(sleep_seconds);

    let file = File::open("file.lock")?;

    println!("{}: Preparing to lock file.", sleep_seconds);
    file.lock_exclusive()?; // block until this process can lock the file
    println!("{}: Obtained lock.", sleep_seconds);

    sleep(sleep_duration);

    println!("{}: Sleep completed", sleep_seconds);
    file.unlock()?;
    println!("{}: Released lock, returning", sleep_seconds);

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't really see how it is any better than the "base" solution with temp file & rename I described in my question. This one has an external crate dependency, requires the reader to also acquire locks, and is generally more risky. I think file-level locking is great when you want to synchronize access to an existing file, which you read from and write to many times. In my case we are talking about a single create&write operation (no subsequent writes after that)

Answer (score 0):

The [`tempfile`](https://docs.rs/tempfile/latest/tempfile/) crate is a convenient option. `NamedTempFile` has a [`persist`](https://docs.rs/tempfile/latest/tempfile/struct.NamedTempFile.html#method.persist) method that performs the atomic rename.

```
let final_path = std::path::Path::new("some/dir/file");
let mut file = tempfile::NamedTempFile::new_in(final_path.parent().unwrap())?;
file.write_all(b"some data")?;
file.persist(final_path)?;
```

This just does the same thing as your solution, although it is also implemented to work on Windows.

The temp file and final file must be on the same filesystem, which is why `new_in` explicitly specifies the temp directory.